# Dockerfile RUN command omits characters starts with "$" from a string

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to print the following string to a file:

```
"hellow world $xHbbbbbbbb"
```

I can do it in two options:

```
printf "hellow world \$xHbbbbbbbb\n" > /myfile1  
echo "hellow world \$xHbbbbbbbb\n" > /myfile2
```

It works fine on a terminal.
When I build it with Dockerfile like that:

```
cat > Deleteme <<EOF
FROM alpine:latest
RUN printf "hellow world \$xHbbbbbbbb\n" > /myfile1
RUN echo "hellow world \$xHbbbbbbbb\n" > /myfile2
EOF

docker build -t deleteme -f Deleteme .  
docker run --rm -it deleteme sh -c "cat /myfile1 && cat /myfile2"
```

The output is:

```
hellow world 
hellow world \n
```

Why the `RUN` command omits `$xHbbbbbbbb` ?
I suppose it because of the `$` which identify it as variable but it works for me on the terminal so I don't understand why it doesn't work on the Dockerfile too.
How can I write the following string to a file:

```
"hellow world $xHbbbbbbbb"
```

Comment: Use double backslash `\\$xHbbbbbbbb`

Comment: @ponury-kostek it doesn't work:  ```Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> caf27325b298
Step 2/2 : RUN echo "hellow world \\n" > /myfile2
 ---> Running in 04e688ab920a
 ---> 381811b5961e
Removing intermediate container 04e688ab920a
Successfully built 381811b5961e
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `cat > Deleteme <<'EOF'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dockerfile, `$xHbbbbbbbb` indeed evaluates to an environment variable
(see [Docker Documentation | Environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) for usage and examples).

To get the desired outcome, you'll need to escape both `\` and `$`.
Also, in `echo`, `\n` won't be interpreted as a newline, unless the `-e` option is specified, but it looks like you could omit it (see [echo man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) for more).

Putting it together:

```
cat > Deleteme <<EOF
FROM alpine:latest
RUN printf "hellow world \\\$xHbbbbbbbb\n" > /myfile1
RUN echo "hellow world \\\$xHbbbbbbbb" > /myfile2
EOF
```

Results with the following `Deleteme` file:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN printf "hellow world \$xHbbbbbbbb\n" > /myfile1
RUN echo "hellow world \$xHbbbbbbbb" > /myfile2
```

And `docker` output:

```
hellow world $xHbbbbbbbb
hellow world $xHbbbbbbbb
```